# Dropbox Javascript longpoll CORS issue

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, cors, dropbox-api

I'm implementing Dropbox's "/list_folder/longpoll" call through their API in Javascript. As described [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/85), the API call fails due to a cross-domain access control error.

Dropbox recommends a hacky workaround that goes against W3C standards: setting an invalid "Content-Type" header "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack", which somehow helps to comply with requirements for a "simple cross-site request" and therefore skips the cross-domain check. Because this is against the web standards, the browser modifies the header back to a valid form, and the API call always fails.

I discovered a couple possible workarounds for this:

1. Using own server to divert the call from browser->dropbox to browser->own server->dropbox. Make an ajax call to the server, server makes a cURL request to dropbox, everything works fine.

   This method's drawback is that you have to actually have a capable server with spare resources to keep all your user's longpoll connections open. I wasn't able to implement this in PHP efficiently.
2. Using Javascript's new fetch() method instead of XMLHttpRequest. It seems to allow setting the invalid header, and the API call works fine. Setting a normal (not the hacky one) header results in a failed call.

   The drawback of this method is browser support. Without the fetch polyfill only Chrome and Firefox supports this. Using the polyfill theoretically adds support for IE and Safari too. But because the polyfill is based on XMLHttpRequest, the headers are changed back to valid ones, as they would be when using plain XMLHttpRequest. Except for IE, where the invalid headers don't get changed back, because IE.

I went with the second workaround, so now I'm left without Safari support.

My question is this: how to solve this problem? Maybe by somehow making PHP handle long (1-2 minute) cURL calls more efficiently? Or maybe by somehow hacking my way into a cross-browser solution of setting an invalid Content-Type header?

I'm thinking about iframes, but this is getting a little ridiculous :)

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Dropbox-Javascript-longpoll-CORS-issue/m-p/200186#M9362 ]

Comment: This should be working now. Please let us know if you're still seeing any issues.